How many cache lines does the adjacent cache line prefetcher bring into cache?
I was investigating the effectiveness of the adjacent cache line prefetcher and its impact on the number of cache lines prefetched from DRAM. Initially, I assumed it fetched only one more adjacent line.
My goal was to determine if and how many cache lines the prefetcher was bringing. The only relevant information I found was in the "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manual" regarding the 0X1A4 MSR register. This register indicated a value of 0 on my Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6442Y (4th Gen), suggesting all prefetchers were enabled.
Experiment Design:

Allocated a 1GB random array of uint64_t values (exceeding my 128MB
L3 cache) and initialized them with values 1-20.
Read 8 random indicies from the intialized array, ensuring the indices were aligned to 4 cache lines alignment.
Used the accumulated sum modulo operation to randomly select an
adjacent line to an accessed cache line.
Introduced a variable to    prevent excessive out-of-order execution.
Compiled with simple "-O2" flag with GCC

Code Snippet:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 135000000 // 1GB array
#define CACHELINE_SIZE 64
#define ALIGN32(x) ((x) & ~(31))
#define ELEMENT_SIZE sizeof(uint64_t)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  uint64_t *array =
      (uint64_t *)aligned_alloc(256, (ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(uint64_t)));

  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: ./a.out <offset in Bytes> \n");
    return 1;
  }

  int offset = atoi(argv[1]);
  int cacheline_offsets = (offset * ELEMENT_SIZE) / (CACHELINE_SIZE);
  printf("Number of cachelines offset is %d\n",cacheline_offsets);

  // Initialize the array
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    array[i] = rand() % 20;
  }

  // Measure execution time
  unsigned long sum = 0;
  uint64_t indices[8] = {0};

  clock_t start = clock();
  for (uint64_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i += 8) {
    uint64_t oldSum = sum;
    for (uint64_t j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      indices[j] = (rand() ^ oldSum) % ARRAY_SIZE;
      indices[j] = ALIGN32(indices[j]);
      sum += array[indices[j]];
    }
    sum += array[indices[sum % 8] + offset];
  }
  clock_t end = clock();

  double time_taken = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("Time taken: %f seconds\n", time_taken);
  printf("sum value: %ld\n", sum); // Use `sum` so it wont be optimized out

  free(array);
  return 0;
}

The results:

Expected vs. Observed Behavior:
Expected best performance for accessing the same cache line.
Predicted slightly worse performance for accessing an adjacent line(s) prefetched by the hardware (maybe 1-2 additional cache lines).
Anticipated a further performance drop for accessing lines further away.
However, the observed results show a different pattern where the same results are for the next (7!) adjacent cache lines and the drop isn't that big as I expected it to be ( I thought it would be 10x since its DRAM miss and not L1 miss)
Question:
Could the observed performance discrepancies be due to flaws in my experimental design or incorrect assumptions?
Are there alternative approaches for measuring the impact of the adjacent cache line prefetcher?

There are many level of caches, if you can invalidate it (e.g. reading a lot more memory, outside your block), you may get more difference (and so maybe you can notice better the trend). But I do not know if it "solve" the problem.

It is quite hard to test individual cache line behaviour in a system with 3 levels of cache and an instruction cache as well. This thread about the surprisingly much faster behaviour of sequential writes to a cache line comes close to testing what you want to know and the timing graphs there show roughly when each level of cache becomes saturated. The L1 cache predictor is quite smart about accesses at fixed strides.

"This register indicated a value of 0 ... suggesting all prefetchers were enabled." hmm... I would expect zero to mean disabled but... what do I know
